# How to background a process via proc_open and have access to STDIN?

Tags: php, linux, shell, stdin

I'm happily using `proc_open` to pipe data into another PHP process.
something like this

```
$spec = array (
    0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
    // I don't need output pipes
);
$cmd = 'php -f another.php >out.log 2>err.log';
$process = proc_open( $cmd, $spec, $pipes );
fwrite( $pipes[0], 'hello world');
fclose( $pipes[0] );
proc_close($process);
```

In the other PHP file I echo STDIN with:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://stdin');
```

This works fine, but not when I background it. Simply by appending `$cmd` with `&` I get nothing from STDIN. I must be missing something fundamental.

It also fails with `fgets(STDIN)`

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write to STDIN of a background process (at least, not in the normal way).

[This question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process) may give you some idea of how to work around this problem.

Unrelated: you say do don't need outputs in the spec, yet you specify them im your `$cmd`; you can write `$spec` like this:

```
$spec = array (
    0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
    1 => array('file', 'out.log', 'w'), // or 'a' to append
    2 => array('file', 'err.log', 'w'),
);
```